# How to get unique css selector with cheerio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cheerio

I have the following html snippet, and I want to get unique selectors for each node with cheerio package.
e.g.

"lorem with id" node should be **#my-id**

"lorem ipsum" node should be **body > div.my-class:nth-child(1) > div:first-child**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="my-class">
      <div id="my-id">lorem with id</div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-class">
      <div>lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? I don't see any Node/Cheerio code here.

Comment: I actually found a package https://github.com/bertyhell/cheerio-get-css-selector, but I can't make it work with my Angular code. If you look into the source code it breaks on el.get(0).tagName somehow.